# Print terminal output in gedit automatically?

Tags: command-line, bash, time-command

the command

```
time ./myprog
```

displays the time it took to run myprog on the screen. Now i would like to write this information to a text file.

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a path `time` is the shell built-in, and its output does not get redirected. Instead, you can use the `time` program, in `/usr/bin/time` which will write to stderr:

```
/usr/bin/time -p ./myprog 2> timing.txt && gedit timing.txt
```

I added `-p` so the output is similar to the output of the `time` built-in.

Comment: that one actually solved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I should have tested this!

Kees is very correct. `time` is a shell builtin in most cases so its output doesn't flow through STDOUT like other programs would normally. You can use the command version sitting in but to save having two identical answers (or me deleting mine), here's another way to capture things that don't output in a traditional way.

```
bash -c "time ./myprog" 2>&1 > file.txt
```

Same principals as before exist. If you want gedit to load after this, wump on `&& gedit file.txt`, if you want it to append, change `>` for `>>`.

If your command is very noisy and you just want the times, you could run the output through `tail`:

```
bash -c "time ./myprog" 2>&1 | tail -3 > file.txt && gedit file.txt
```

---

#### Old answer

To just save it to a file just do this:

```
time ./myprog > file.txt
```

You don't need the `.txt` extension but it might help you. If you want to append to the file (instead of replacing it), swap the `>` for `>>`.

If you want this showing up in gedit specifically, you need to save it to a file and then open it in gedit. I can't see a way of piping the text directly into gedit without saving it first.

```
time ./myprog > file.txt && gedit file.txt
```

Comment: nice one =D! I actually learned something (>>) +1

Comment: > it does not work:> the file (file.txt) is indeed created but remains empty. What did i do wrong ? PS: i actually have to type './myprog ./ mydatat' to use myprog. Can it be because of this ?

Comment: @kwak I updated the post.

Comment: > thanks. I already accepted Kees's answer, but both solve my problem. (i.e. i have up voted both).

Comment: @kwak I've no problem with that - They both do pretty much the same thing. I just wanted to show a different way of doing this just in case somebody else has an issue with output redirection.

Comment: ad "without saving it first" that's what `tmp`'s for, no? E.g. `my_cmd > /tmp/bla_.txt && gedit /tmp/bla_.txt`

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Yeah, if that's what you want.

Comment: on this case why use stdErr @Oli?